# Add a conversion filter to guzzle response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

There's a remote service I was using which returns a base64 encoded PDF. I was using this as follows:

```
$fp = fopen($url, "r");
$fn = md5($url).".pdf";
stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.base64-decode');
\Storage::drive("public")->put($fn,$fp);
return response()->json(["url"=>\Storage::drive("public")->url($fn)]);
```

This was used to download and write the PDF file on the public disk so I could give a link to it to users without having to load the entire file in memory. Problem here being that the files are large (50mb PDF so larger in base64).

This was working fine until the remote server decided to add an internal redirect which `fopen` can't handle.
Rather than writing my own solution to handle the internal redirect I decided to transition my code to use Guzzle.

This is what I tried:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request("GET", $url);
$fp = $res->getBody();
$fn = md5($url).".pdf";
stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.base64-decode'); //Works without this
\Storage::drive("public")->put($fn,$fp);
return response()->json(["url"=>\Storage::drive("public")->url($fn)]);
```

The problem is `stream_filter_append`, code works fine without it. The error I get is

> stream_filter_append() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Is there any way to append a stream filter on the body of a guzzle response?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this I had to get the underlying resource from the guzzle stream. Apparently Guzzle is very happy to provide this, here's my code:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request("GET", $url);
$fp = $res->getBody()->dettach(); //The magic method.
$fn = md5($url).".pdf";
stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.base64-decode'); //Works without this
\Storage::drive("public")->put($fn,$fp);
return response()->json(["url"=>\Storage::drive("public")->url($fn)]);
```

Note: that the `dettach` method does what the name suggests and detaches the stream from Guzzle so any subsequent uses of `$res->getBody()->read()` will not do anything. This is probably not ideal but I don't know if there's any other way around this.